# How to encode 'á' to '&#225' with C# ?? (UTF8)

Tags: c#, xml, encoding, utf-8

I'm trying to write an XML file with UTF-8 encode, and the original string can have invalid characters like 'á', so, i need to change these invalid characters to a valid ones.

I know that there is an encoding method that take, for example, character `á` and transform it to group of characters `&#225;`.

I am trying to achive this with C#but i have no succes on it. I am using Encoding.UTF8 functions but i only end with the sema character (i.e: á) or a '?' character.

So, do you know with is the correct way to achive this character change with C# ??

Thanks for your time and help :)

LLORENS

Comment: Are you using an XMLWriter of any sort? all of them should take care of this already.

Comment: I don't think `&#225` is a valid XML entity -- that looks like an ANSI code point,and XML entities should always be encoded as Unicode code points.  As others have pointed out, you'd be much better off if you just inserted the real UTF-8 encoded byte sequence into the XML file.

Comment: Wait, are you trying to create an XML file in UTF-8 format with these characters inside, or are you trying to create an ASCII-encoded XML file with entities like `&#225;`?

Comment: @Daniel, `&#225;` is [right](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00e1/index.htm), but I agree there's no need for an entity here.

Comment: Hi, first of all thanks for your answers. Yes, i am trying to write and ASCII-encoded XML that can have characters like 'á', i am usings XML objects of C# framework to construct the XML structure (i.e: XmlDocument, XmlNode, etc.) and then, call the 'outerstring' function to get the final string that i can write to file.

But i admit that i found myself confused about all of this encoding systems, and i dont know if i am right trying to change 'á' character by '&#225' sequence.

Comment: StreamWriter already encodes to utf8 by default.  Don't help, you'll break it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

á is not an "invalid" character.  It has a UTF-8 encoding (bytes 195 and 161), and Nick is right that if you construct everything correctly this will be transparent.

Answer (score 5):

You can use any one method.

Here are 4 ways you can encode XML in C#:

1. string.Replace() 5 times

This is ugly but it works. Note that `Replace("&", "&amp;")` has to be the first replace so we don't replace other already escaped &.

```
string xml = "<node>it's my \"node\" & i like it<node>";
encodedXml = xml.Replace("&","&amp;").Replace("<","&lt;").Replace(">","&gt;").Replace("\"", "&quot;").Replace("'", "&apos;");

// RESULT: &lt;node&gt;it&apos;s my &quot;node&quot; &amp; i like it&lt;node&gt;
```

2. System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode()

Used for encoding HTML, but HTML is a form of XML so we can use that too. Mostly used in ASP.NET apps. Note that HtmlEncode does NOT encode apostrophes ( ' ).

```
string xml = "<node>it's my \"node\" & i like it<node>";
string encodedXml = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(xml);

// RESULT: &lt;node&gt;it's my &quot;node&quot; &amp; i like it&lt;node&gt;
```

3. System.Security.SecurityElement.Escape()

In Windows Forms or Console apps I use this method. If nothing else it saves me including the System.Web reference in my projects and it encodes all 5 chars.

```
string xml = "<node>it's my \"node\" & i like it<node>";
string encodedXml = System.Security.SecurityElement.Escape(xml);

// RESULT: &lt;node&gt;it&apos;s my &quot;node&quot; &amp; i like it&lt;node&gt;
```

4. System.Xml.XmlTextWriter

Using XmlTextWriter you don't have to worry about escaping anything since it escapes the chars where needed. For example in the attributes it doesn't escape apostrophes, while in node values it doesn't escape apostrophes and qoutes.

```
string xml = "<node>it's my \"node\" & i like it<node>";
using (XmlTextWriter xtw = new XmlTextWriter(@"c:\xmlTest.xml", Encoding.Unicode))
{

    xtw.WriteStartElement("xmlEncodeTest");
    xtw.WriteAttributeString("testAttribute", xml);
    xtw.WriteString(xml);
    xtw.WriteEndElement();

}

// RESULT:
/*
<xmlEncodeTest testAttribute="&lt;node&gt;it's my &quot;node&quot; &amp; i like it&lt;node&gt;">
    &lt;node&gt;it's my "node" &amp; i like it&lt;node&gt;
</xmlEncodeTest>
*/
```

[http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2008/10/21/Different-ways-how-to-escape-an-XML-string-in-C.aspx]

Comment: Very good explanation. I like know what the different mechanisms do under the covers. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
    private static string Escape(string content)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        var settings = new XmlWriterSettings 
        { 
            ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment 
        };

        using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(sb, settings))
            xmlWriter.WriteString(content);

        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Some explanation would be nice

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what you need:
(found at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20255/Full-HTML-Character-Encoding-in-C)

```
//for example this transforms "čas" to "&#269;as"
public static string HtmlEncode(string text)
    {
        char[] chars = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(text).ToCharArray();
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(text.Length + (int)(text.Length * 0.1));

        foreach (char c in chars)
        {
            int value = Convert.ToInt32(c);
            if (value > 127)
                result.AppendFormat("&#{0};", value);
            else
                result.Append(c);
        }

        return result.ToString();
    }
```